# How to configure Apache server and node server in one domain?

Tags: node.js, apache

I had trouble studying.

I'm making my own sns app like Facebook or Instagram.
So I completed the timeline feature, so this time I'm going to create a chat. So I want to make a chat function using node.js + socket.io.
That's why I wonder how to build a node.js server.

My development environment is Ubuntu 18.04 + apache2 + Mysql (+ Let ’s Encrypt SSL And I have a domain)

Even if I searched on google and looked up I couldn't create an https node.js server.

Can't someone help me easily and in detail?

android is from Api 29
https communication is recommended by default. You can communicate with http on api 29 but that's not a long term solution. That's why I configured my server with https. I will never change it to http.

Assume the Domain is called test.com.

> The following is the setting in my 000-default.conf file.
>
> vi  /etc/apache2/sites-availabls/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Redirect / https://test.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/cert.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem

<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Options All -Indexes
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Port 80 is known as http communication. So I redirected to https uri.

So I basically know that port 443 is the port for https communication.
Anyway, the important thing is that my Apache server is using port 80 and port 443. Here we want to create a node.js socket server that can chat with https communication. It would be really helpful if you helped me easily and in detail.

> Root path of the server -> /var/www/html/
>
> php folder path to use in android -> /var/www/html/android
>
> User profile picture folder path to use on android -> /var/www/html/android/image

I want to create a node.js file in the following path.

> File folder for chatting on android. -> /var/www/html/android/chat

I searched on Google but it all failed. Otherwise, all the examples I saw ran only one node.js server.

I tried proxypass or proxypassreverse or Something but Failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your server on any free port on your server machine

```
var https = require('https');
https.createServer(options, app).listen(ANY_PORT);
```

and in your android code specify the port to connect to

```
val url = URL("https://test.com:ANY_PORT")
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is have a reverse proxy with apache. See the docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

What this really means is that say your php stuff is running on port 80 and 443. However, now you have a node service running on port 3000.

Though, you want to mask port 3000 as port 80. So you can say you have domain.com/chat running your port. So you listen for any routes that hit that path and forward them off to the application running that service.

Answer (score 0):

Install Letsencrypt from certbot.eff.org by following the instructions and use this command. Select the `No Redirect` option at the installation.

```
sudo certbot --apache
```

Copy the `privkey.pem` and `fullchain.pem` from your certificate folder using the below command

```
sudo cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem ~/nodejs-rootfolder
sudo cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem ~/nodejs-rootfolder
```

`nodejs-rootfolder` is where you have kept the `Node.js` server project

Mention the below code in your `index.js` or `server.js` file.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '500mb' }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
var fs = require('fs');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem');

var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
   res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.header('origin') || req.header('x- forwarded-host') || req.header('referer') $
   res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
   res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,PUT,DELETE');
   res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization,Access-control-request-headers,i$
   if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) return res.send(200);
   next();
});
var port = process.env.PORT || 5001;
httpsServer.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

The `certbot --apache` will do all the installations and setup for SSL configuration. With the above-listed workaround, you can get it done. However, if you want your server to redirect all `HTTP` to `HTTPS` then use the below config.

> `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =test.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

> Then perform
>   `sudo service apache2 restart`